# Fuzzing server written in Python with SPIKE

Tags: python, flask, testing, server, fuzzing

I wanted to build a fuzzer in SPIKE, for my own server written in Python. But I didn't found any useful guids or tutorials, only a few  scripts.

In server I have login page  [image] What I want to do is to send random data to login and password...

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_session import Session
import sqlite3

app = Flask("Flask - Lab")

DATABASE = 'library_database.db'

sess = Session()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    con = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from books")
    con.commit()
    books = \
        cur.fetchall()
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form['login']
        password = request.form['password']
        if len(user) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
            session['admin'] = False
            session['user'] = False
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        cur.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (user, password))
        con.commit()
        admin = cur.fetchone()
        if admin and admin[0] == 1:
            session['admin'] = True
            session['user'] = False
            return render_template('main_view_admin.html', books=books)
        elif admin and admin[0] == 0:
            session['admin'] = False
            session['user'] = True
            return render_template('main_view.html', books=books)
        else:
            return render_template('login.html')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        if 'admin' in session and session['admin']:
            return render_template('main_view_admin.html', books=books)
        elif 'user' in session:
            return render_template('main_view.html', books=books)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    con.close()

app.debug = True
app.secret_key = "secret_key"
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Does anyone know SPIKE or have any  links that might be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You might try a more modern version of Spike. Sulley was Spike's successor, and boofuzz is likewise a successor fork of Sulley. https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz/ There's a simple HTTP demo available at https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz-http You'll need to do some leg work on your request, but you might start by using Wireshark to sniff regular HTTP requests back and forth between the client and server. A normal request could give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use python manage.py createsuperuser in your virtual environment on the python command line.  That will create the user in the sqllite3 database an allow you to login.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).